# Are there any racing wheels that support both XBOX 360 and PS3?

Tags: xbox-360, ps3, controllers

I swear I came across one that did a couple years ago (had some kind of weird dongle that would allow it to work on pretty much everything), but I could be thinking of something else.  I'd rather not have to buy two different wheels...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [this one](http://www.engadget.com/2008/10/31/fanatecs-porsche-911-turbo-s-racing-wheel-plays-on-xbox-360-ps/) can do what you are asking. 
Dont't any details though.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for!